# JasperReports: display a column or field if it is visible else do not display

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a requirement in JasperReports wherein I need to display the field based on a user's configuration. If the field is visible to the user then display the field else the field will be hidden. Can anybody please suggest me the solution for this?

Comment: Are you using iReport? or just creating your report in java code?

Comment: @Dawood You can pass parameter to the report with help of JasperReports API. After that you can use `printWhenExpression` expression

Comment: @HenriqueMiranda, yes I am using iReport.

Comment: @Alex-k, thnx alex, will give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `parameter` for setting condition to hide the field or not.

The one way is to set `parameter` with help of [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html).

The sample code for setting parameter and building report:

```java
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("isFieldHidden", true);

JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(report, parameters, connection);
```

The snippet of the report template (jrxml file):

```xml
<parameter name="isFieldHidden" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
...
<textField>
    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{isFieldHidden}]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{city}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```